# More allowed ip's (logical-operators)

Tags: php, logical-operators

I have an maintenance mode, and there is 1 IP address that is allowed to access the website while the maintenance mode is turned on.

My code:

```
// Maintenance
$maintenance = 1; // 0 = off, 1 = on
if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "00.00.000.00" && $maintenance )
{
//Display Maintenance Page
die(include('maintenance.php'));
}
```

How can I add a few more IP addresses that are allowed to access the website while the maintenance mode is turned on? 
I tried some things, but it didn't worked.

Comment: It is better to do this on the level of the http server, not inside php.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha Fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people with the same problem, I fixed it by doing this:

In the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.enable -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
```

Your maintenance page is maintenance.html and your switch is maintenance.enable. You can enable maintenance by making a empty file called maintenance.enable, and if you want to turn it off you delete this file. Fill in your IP, by removing AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD and typing your own IP.